How come the 2nd exit button is not fading in after clicking the 1st exit button?
The 1st exit button (.exitA) fades in without an issue.
The 2nd exit button (.exitB) should fade in after the curtain goes up.
It does not.
How do I fix this?
https://jsfiddle.net/8c4e129f/
.exitA,
.exitB {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.exitA.visible,
.exitB.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}




function showExit(containerSelector, exitSelector) {
    const container = document.querySelector(containerSelector);
    const closeButton = document.querySelector(exitSelector);
    container.classList.remove("hide");
    container.classList.add("slide");
    container.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
      closeButton.classList.add("visible");
    });
  }


  function removePlayer() {
    videoPlayer.destroyPlayers();
  }

  function resetPage() {
    hideContainer(".video-containerA");
    // showContainer(".video-containerB");
    showExit(".video-containerB",".exitB");
    removePlayer();
  }


at a guess container.addEventListener("transitionend" never fires

also, the curtain container B has no transition, it has an animation

@JaromandaX Can you answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78393256/after-i-click-the-x-button-the-curtain-should-go-up Can you take a look at it.

isn't that just this question asked 4 hours ago? My guess is, you're still listening for the wrong event on the wrong element, just like you do here

In the resetPage function you call hideContainer with ".video-containerA", but video-containerA already got hidden on page load, so it doesn't transition to anything this time and transitionend doesn't fire

@Lennholm Can you answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78393256/after-i-click-the-x-button-the-curtain-should-go-up Can you take a look at it.

@Jaromanda X Can transition work to have the curtain go up after clicking the 1st exit button?

Of course it can - it does when you load the page for conatiner A

@JaromandaX Can you show me how please? I can't figure it out. Can you provide it as an answer on there?

@JaromandaX Can you show me?
